# Connecting siblings in binary search tree

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect the siblings of the binary search tree. You can find the logic in the Connect() method. My question is, is there any better way to do it? Am I overdoing by using two queues to implement the logic?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleCSParallel
{
    class Tree
    {
        public Tree left = null;
        public Tree right = null;
        public Tree sibling = null;
        public int _data;

        Tree(int data)
        {
            _data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }

        public Tree Left
        {
            get
            {
                return this.left;
            }
        }

        public Tree Right
        {
            get
            {
                return this.right;
            }
        }

        public Tree AddNode(Tree node, int data)
        {
            if (node == null)
            {
                node = new Tree(data);
                return node;
            }
            else if (node._data <= data)
            {
                node.left = AddNode(node.left, data);
            }
            else if (node._data > data)
            {
                node.right = AddNode(node.right, data);
            }
            return node;
        }

        public static Tree CreateTree(Tree node, int depth, int start)
        {
            if (node == null)
                node = new Tree(start);
            if (depth > 1)
            {
                node.left = CreateTree(node.left, depth - 1, start + 1);
                node.right = CreateTree(node.right, depth - 1, start + 1);
            }
            return node;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Tree node = null;
            Tree tr = Tree.CreateTree(null, 4, 1);
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            int total = WalkTree(tr);           
            TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("in {0} sec", ts.Seconds);
            Console.WriteLine("total:{0}", total);
            connect(tr);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }        

        static void connect(Tree root)
        {
            Queue<Tree> nodeQueue = new Queue<Tree>();          
            nodeQueue.Enqueue(root);
            Console.WriteLine(root._data);
            connectSiblings(nodeQueue);
        }

        static void connectSiblings(Queue<Tree> nodeQueue)
        {
            Queue<Tree> childrenQueue = new Queue<Tree>();            
            StringBuilder MsgStr = new StringBuilder();
            bool done = false;

             while (!done)
             {
                while (nodeQueue.Count != 0)
                {

                    Tree parent = nodeQueue.Dequeue();                  
                    if (parent.left != null)
                    {
                        childrenQueue.Enqueue(parent.left);
                    }
                    if (parent.right != null)
                    {
                        childrenQueue.Enqueue(parent.right);
                    }           
                }

                 Tree prevNode = null;
                 Tree currNode = null;
                while (childrenQueue.Count != 0)
                {
                    currNode = childrenQueue.Dequeue();
                    nodeQueue.Enqueue(currNode);                

                    if (prevNode != null)
                    {                       
                        MsgStr.Append(string.Format("\t{0}",currNode._data));                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prevNode = currNode;                        
                        MsgStr.Append(string.Format("\t{0}",prevNode._data));
                    }           
                }                   
                Console.WriteLine(MsgStr.ToString());
                MsgStr.Remove(0, MsgStr.Length);

                if (nodeQueue.Count == 0 && childrenQueue.Count == 0)
                    done = true;
             }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to connect the siblings in a recursive manner, using an array of prev nodes, one per depth:

```
void connect(Node node, int depth, List<Node> prev)
{
  if (node == null)
    return;
  if(prev.Size <= depth)
    prev.Add(depth);
  else {
    prev[depth].sibling = node;
    prev[depth] = node;
  }
  connect(node.left, depth+1, prev);
  connect(node.right, depth+1, prev);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It worked and this one is more elegant that what I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted the question with space complexity of O(1) in java ..

```
public void setSibling(Node root){
        Node start = null;
        if (root == null) return;
        do{
            if(root.left!=null) {
                root.left.sibling = getNextSibling(root,"left");
                if(start == null) start = root.left;
            }
            if(root.right!=null){
                root.right.sibling = getNextSibling(root,"right");
                if(start == null) start = root.right;
            }
            root = root.sibling;
        }while(root!=null);
        root = start;
        setSibling(root);

    }


    public Node getNextSibling(Node root,String marker){
        if (marker.equals("left")){
            if(root.right!=null)return root.right;
        }
        Node nextSibling = null;
        root = root.sibling;
        while(nextSibling == null && root != null){
            if (root.left != null) nextSibling = root.left;
            else if (root.right != null) nextSibling = root.right;
            else root = root.sibling;
        }
        return nextSibling;
    }
```

Its may not be elegant but it works..